# Subdivided icosphere not rendering right. Incorrect vertices order?

Tags: java, opengl, model, rendering, lwjgl

I am currently working on sub dividing my icosphere and it ends up looking crazy (see below). It works fine if I don't subdivide it at all so I believe the error is either in my recursion for loop or the getMiddlePoint method (see below). My thought on why this is happening is that I am adding the vertices and indices in the wrong order. If this is the case what order should I be adding them in? Any ideas on how to fix this?

Result:

[image: Here]

Recursion for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < RECURSION_LEVEL; i++) {
            List<Vector3i> indices2 = new ArrayList<Vector3i>();
            for (Vector3i face : indices) {
                int a = getMiddlePoint(face.x, face.y);
                int b = getMiddlePoint(face.y, face.z);
                int c = getMiddlePoint(face.z, face.x);

                indices2.add(new Vector3i(face.x, a, c));
                indices2.add(new Vector3i(face.y, b, a));
                indices2.add(new Vector3i(face.z, c, b));
                indices2.add(new Vector3i(a, b, c));
            }
            indices = indices2;
        }
```

getMiddlePoints method:

```
private int getMiddlePoint(int p1, int p2) {
        boolean firstIsSmaller = p1 < p2;
        int smallerIndex = firstIsSmaller ? p1 : p2;
        int greaterIndex = firstIsSmaller ? p2 : p1;
        int key = (smallerIndex << 32) + greaterIndex;

        Integer ret = middlePointIndexCache.get(key);
        if (ret != null) {
            return ret;
        }

        Vector3f point1 = vertices.get(p1);
        Vector3f point2 = vertices.get(p2);
        Vector3f middle = new Vector3f(
                (point1.x + point2.x) / 2.0f,
                (point1.y + point2.y) / 2.0f,
                (point1.z + point2.z) / 2.0f
                );

        int i = addVertex(middle);
        middlePointIndexCache.put(key, i);
        return i;
    }
```

All of the code for my icosphere generator:
(Ignore the texture coordinates they are temporary to prevent my renderer from crashing.)

```
package com.robert.game.planet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.joml.Vector2f;
import org.joml.Vector3f;
import org.joml.Vector3i;

import com.robert.engine.loader.Loader;
import com.robert.engine.models.Mesh;

public class BasePlanetGenerator {

    private List<Vector3f> vertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
    private List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
    private List<Vector3i> indices = new ArrayList<Vector3i>(); // think of this as faces
    private List<Vector2f> textureCoords = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
    private Map<Integer, Integer> middlePointIndexCache = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    private static final int RECURSION_LEVEL = 2;

    private int index = 0;

    float t = (float) ((1.0 + Math.sqrt(5.0)) / 2);

    // Initial vertices
    {
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(-1,  t,  0));
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(1,  t,  0));
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(-1, -t,  0));
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(1, -t,  0));
//      
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(0, -1,  t));
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(0,  1,  t));
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(0, -1, -t));
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(0,  1, -t));
//      
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(t,  0, -1));
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(t,  0,  1));
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(-t,  0, -1));
//      vertices.add(new Vector3f(-t,  0,  1));

        addVertex(new Vector3f(-1,  t,  0));
        addVertex(new Vector3f(1,  t,  0));
        addVertex(new Vector3f(-1, -t,  0));
        addVertex(new Vector3f(1, -t,  0));

        addVertex(new Vector3f(0, -1,  t));
        addVertex(new Vector3f(0,  1,  t));
        addVertex(new Vector3f(0, -1, -t));
        addVertex(new Vector3f(0,  1, -t));

        addVertex(new Vector3f(t,  0, -1));
        addVertex(new Vector3f(t,  0,  1));
        addVertex(new Vector3f(-t,  0, -1));
        addVertex(new Vector3f(-t,  0,  1));
    }

    // Initial indices
    {
        indices.add(new Vector3i(0, 11, 5));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(0, 5, 1));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(0, 1, 7));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(0, 7, 10));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(0, 10, 11));

        indices.add(new Vector3i(1, 5, 9));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(5, 11, 4));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(11, 10, 2));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(10, 7, 6));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(7, 1, 8));

        indices.add(new Vector3i(3, 9, 4));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(3, 4, 2));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(3, 2, 6));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(3, 6, 8));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(3, 8, 9));

        indices.add(new Vector3i(4, 9, 5));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(2, 4, 11));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(6, 2, 10));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(8, 6, 7));
        indices.add(new Vector3i(9, 8, 1));

//      indices = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {
//              0, 11, 5,
//              0, 5, 1,
//              0, 1, 7,
//              0, 7, 10,
//              0, 10, 11,
//              
//              1, 5, 9,
//              5, 11, 4,
//              11, 10, 2,
//              10, 7, 6,
//              7, 1, 8,
//              
//              3, 9, 4,
//              3, 4, 2,
//              3, 2, 6,
//              3, 6, 8,
//              3, 8, 9,
//              
//              4, 9, 5,
//              2, 4, 11,
//              6, 2, 10,
//              8, 6, 7,
//              9, 8, 1
//      });
    }

    // Inital textureCoords
    {
        textureCoords.add(new Vector2f(1, 1));
    }

    float[] verticesArray;
    int[] indicesArray;
    float[] normalsArray;
    float[] textureCoordsArray;

    public Mesh generateBasePlanet(Loader loader) {

        for (int i = 0; i < RECURSION_LEVEL; i++) {
            List<Vector3i> indices2 = new ArrayList<Vector3i>();
            for (Vector3i face : indices) {
                int a = getMiddlePoint(face.x, face.y);
                int b = getMiddlePoint(face.y, face.z);
                int c = getMiddlePoint(face.z, face.x);

                indices2.add(new Vector3i(face.x, a, c));
                indices2.add(new Vector3i(face.y, b, a));
                indices2.add(new Vector3i(face.z, c, b));
                indices2.add(new Vector3i(a, b, c));
            }
            indices = indices2;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i ++) {
            Vector3f normal = vertices.get(i);
//          normal.normalize();
//          float length = normal.length();     
//          normals.add(new Vector3f(normal.x / length, normal.y / length, normal.z / length));
            normals.add(normal);
        }

        convertToArrays();

        return loader.createMesh(verticesArray, textureCoordsArray, normalsArray, indicesArray);
    }

    private int getMiddlePoint(int p1, int p2) {
        boolean firstIsSmaller = p1 < p2;
        int smallerIndex = firstIsSmaller ? p1 : p2;
        int greaterIndex = firstIsSmaller ? p2 : p1;
        int key = (smallerIndex << 32) + greaterIndex;

        Integer ret = middlePointIndexCache.get(key);
        if (ret != null) {
            return ret;
        }

        Vector3f point1 = vertices.get(p1);
        Vector3f point2 = vertices.get(p2);
        Vector3f middle = new Vector3f(
                (point1.x + point2.x) / 2.0f,
                (point1.y + point2.y) / 2.0f,
                (point1.z + point2.z) / 2.0f
                );

        int i = addVertex(middle);
        middlePointIndexCache.put(key, i);
        return i;
    }

    private void convertToArrays() {
        verticesArray = new float[vertices.size() * 3];
        indicesArray = new int[indices.size() * 3];
        normalsArray = new float[normals.size() * 3];
        textureCoordsArray = new float[textureCoords.size() * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i ++) {        
            Vector3f vertex = vertices.get(i);
            verticesArray[(i * 3)] = vertex.x;
            verticesArray[(i * 3) + 1] = vertex.y;
            verticesArray[(i * 3) + 2] = vertex.z;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i ++) {
            Vector3i indice = indices.get(i);
            indicesArray[(i * 3)] = indice.x;
            indicesArray[(i * 3) + 1] = indice.y;
            indicesArray[(i * 3) + 2] = indice.z;
//          indicesArray[i] = indices.get(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < normals.size(); i ++) {
            Vector3f normal = normals.get(i);
            normalsArray[(i * 3)] = normal.x;
            normalsArray[(i * 3) + 1] = normal.y;
            normalsArray[(i * 3) + 2] = normal.z;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < textureCoords.size(); i ++) {
            textureCoordsArray[(i * 2)] = textureCoords.get(i).x;
            textureCoordsArray[(i * 2) + 1] = textureCoords.get(i).y;
        }
    }

    private int addVertex(Vector3f vector) {
        float length = vector.length();
        vertices.add(new Vector3f(vector.x / length, vector.y / length, vector.z / length));
        return index++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [oracle java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) clearly says:

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>   - For `int`, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive

This means the data type `int` is a integral data type with a size of 32 bits.

In the function `getMiddlePoint`, the line

```
int key = (smallerIndex << 32) + greaterIndex;
```

causes an overflow.

Change it to

```
int key = (smallerIndex << 16) + greaterIndex;
```

and your code will proper work.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't for the life of me figure it out.